# web crawler using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

my question is how to extract information from HTML code where required info is not associated to a unique attribute, for eg :

1.extracting problem link from : `<a href="http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/" style="visibility: visible;">`

if we want to acces links to all the problems using `http://www.spoj.com/problems/***`

2.extracting stock price change(-0.88) from `<span id="ChangePercent">-0.88%</span>`

i made a simple web crawler using findAll() from beautifulSoup, it displays the links to submit solutions to all the problems.
i want it to display the links to all the problems on spoj, hence need to supply findAll() with a unique property of the problem link in HTML code (inspect element at a problem link).

i tried :

```
url = 'http://www.spoj.com/problems/classical/sort=0,start=' + str(page)
source_code = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text)
# print(soup)

for link in soup.findAll('a', {'href':'http://www.spoj.com/problems/' + '.+.'}):
    href = link.get('href')
    print(str(href))
```

- (a period) -- matches any single character except newline '\n'
- - -- 1 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left, e.g. 'i+' = one or more i's

i know the bug is in '.+.' part, and need help to find a solution..

my python code printing links to submit links : http://ideone.com/4ZLcSV

Answer (score 0):

Using re:

```
import re
rr = re.findall(r'href="(/problems/[^"]+).*?problem\.">([0-9\.^<]+)', \
source_code.text, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
for url, p in rr:
    print url, p
```

Will print something like this:

 `/problems/classical/ 25.03
 /problems/DYZIO/ 30.75
 /problems/SUPPER/ 30.49
 /problems/PICAD/ 14.25`